# Amchart validateData() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I made graph like this.

```
stockPanel = new AmCharts.StockPanel(AmCharts.themes.dark);
stockPanel.title = "Old Title”;
.
.
.
chart = new AmCharts.AmStockChart(AmCharts.themes.dark);
chart.id = "main chart";
chart.panels = [stockPanel];
```

then I would like to change the element of graphs dynamically, so I tested this code.

(These code is called after button pressed)

```
console.log(stockPanel.title); // show 'Old Title'
stockPanel.title = "NewTitle"; // 
console.log(stockPanel.title);// show 'New Title'
console.log(chart.id); // show 'main chart'
chart.validateData(); // seems not to work.
```

The graph doesn't change.

Is there any action I should do more??

Comment: Could you create a [codepen](https://codepen.io/) with your code? Here is an example how to get it setup: https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/59da2335de7488d615539aad1a9a01fe

Comment: Thanks for your help, but `You're not allowed to fork a private Pen.` can't save my code.

Comment: I made it public. Try again.

Comment: @Darlesson I edited the code. please push the button `Please Push` on lower left, I would like to change the top panel title but in vain.

Comment: Your changes didn't take effect. Have you tried [validateNow](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmStockChart#validateNow)?

Comment: Yes I have tried validateNow in that codepen sample. thanks very much , for now I am trying work-around way. it it works I will report.